# AEM /welcome not redirecting to /libs/cq/core/content/welcome.html

Tags: aem, apache-felix

AEM /welcome not redirecting to /libs/cq/core/content/welcome.html

It is showing blank page.

Below text getting in error log:

WARN : GET /welcome HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.servlets.get.impl.RedirectServlet RedirectServlet: Servlet is included, not redirecting

Where exactly this redirection rule configured. How to debug this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is configured here /libs/cq/core/content/welcome

[image]

You can use http://localhost:4502/system/console/jcrresolver?msg=RedirectResource%2C+type%3Dsling%3Aredirect%2C+path%3D%2Fwelcome%2C+values%3D%7Bsling%3Atarget%3D%2Flibs%2Fcq%2Fcore%2Fcontent%2Fwelcome.html%2C+sling%3Astatus%3D302%7D&test=%2Fwelcome to debug it

Comment: Everything fine there, the problem is /welcome is not redirecting. If I open http://localhost:4502/libs/cq/core/content/welcome.html it is working

Comment: are you seeing an entry in `/system/console/jcrresolver` for `/welcome`.
Do a browser search (ctrl + f) on this page for `/libs/cq/core/content/welcome$1`, check if you're seeing redirect as `external: 302` and pattern as `^[^/]+/[^/]+/welcome(\..*)` against it.